# error with app:mergeDebugResources on android studio 3.5

Tags: android

I have a problem with app:mergeDebugResources on android studio 3.5, so I can't run my app on my mobile device

> What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
> Could not find aapt2-windows.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.5.0-5435860).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.5.0-5435860/aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-windows.jar

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
1:24:30 PM: Task execution finished 'mergeDebugResources'.

Answer (score 0):

find this

```
    jcenter()
maven {
    url "https://maven.google.com"
}
```

and replace with

```
    maven {
    url "https://maven.google.com"
          }
    jcenter()
```